# Container padding in Neat/Bourbon

Tags: sass, css-frameworks, bourbon, neat

I am working with Neat the first time. I am wondering how I can accomplish a padding for the outer .container. When giving the container a padding, the width of the columns within aren't right anymore and shift to the right/left.

Like this one:

```
<header>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='logo'>
      <img alt='Logo' src='assets/images/logo.png'>
    </div>
  </div>
</header> 



.container
{
  @include outer-container;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

header
{
  .logo
  {
    @include span-columns( 3 );
  }
}
```

**I know I could give the first element in the container a padding and the columns would adjust, but that isn't a consistent solution imho.**

What is the best practice to use a consistent padding to the outer container without changing the columns within?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Give my Sass grid plugin a go :) http://www.sassygrids.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible in Neat 1.6, but it is a known issue that looks like it [might be solved in Neat 2.0](https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/issues/99#issuecomment-29143122).