# Using bourbon/bourbon neat with Yeoman without errors

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, yeoman, bourbon

I just started using Yeoman and so far it works great.

I wanted to replace compass with Bourbon/bourbon neat which is where I run into issues. I followed [this tutorial](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/getting-started-with-sass-bourbon-and-neat-with-yeoman) but when I run "grunt serve" I get issues. It doesn't seem to be compiling my scss into a css file. I've checked the directory and there is no file there.

I tried getting the guys at thoughtbot to help out but no response yet.

Any help would be great.

Here is my gruntfile.js for reference.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9830212/Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just spent the last hour trying to figure this out myself — hopefully the following fixes will work for you, too.

First off, I'm presuming the error you're getting is:

`Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'app' of undefined).`

The reason this is happening is because the Gruntfile for `generator-webapp` has (I suppose somewhat recently) updated the project variable from `yeoman` to `config` — which means the `yeoman.app` method is no longer valid. So:

**1. Change all instances of `<%= yeoman.app %>` to `<%= config.app %>`**

This will resolve the CL errors. However, [Thoughtbot's article](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/getting-started-with-sass-bourbon-and-neat-with-yeoman) also provides inaccurate instructions for including the Bourbon and Neat styles in your `main.scss`, as the `@import 'bourbon'` and `@import 'neat'` calls won't be looking in the right directories. I'm sure there are more elegant ways of fixing this, but my solution was simply to provide the absolute references:

**2a. Import Bourbon with `@import '../bower_components/bourbon/dist/bourbon';`**
**2b. Import Neat with `@import '../bower_components/neat/app/assets/stylesheets/neat';`**

After saving these changes, make sure to stop `grunt serve` if it's currently running. When you start it up again, you should be error-free and have a properly built `main.css` file.

For reference, I've uploaded my complete Gruntfile after having made these changes: [gist.github.com/colepeters/11155980](https://gist.github.com/colepeters/11155980)

Hope this helps!

(By the way, I'll try and ping Thoughtbot with these issues so the article can be updated.)

Comment: hmm ok, it's now working but I am getting errors. See below.    Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "      webkit-image": expected ")", was ": -webkit- + $p..."
        on line 21 of app/bower_components/bourbon/dist/helpers/_linear-angle-parser.scss
        from line 9 of app/bower_components/bourbon/dist/_bourbon.scss
        from line 1 of app/sass/main.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
Warning: Exited with error code 1 Use --force to continue.

Comment: ah, I've got it figured out. What you suggested worked, plus making sure I am running the latest version of sass. Which I had issues with compass I think, but now that I am using Bourbon I can safely use it.

Comment: I had the same problem trying to make requirejs & yeoman working. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Jorge Awesome, glad to hear this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this same problem today. I would like to thank Cole for the great answer that fixed my first problem **<%= config.app %>**. This is a continuation of the subject at hand.

I spent some time playing around with the Gruntfile.js and found a way to simplify the imports in the stylesheet. *Look around line 38 or so.*

```
options: {
    loadPath: [
    '/Users/username/project/bower_components/bourbon/dist',
    '/Users/username/project/bower_components/neat/app/assets/stylesheets'
     ]
}
```

If you make them local then it works. This allows you to use @import 'bourbon'; and @import "neat';

It's not an elegant solution, but neither am I. I just hope it helps. I will continue to look for a prettier solution.

The toughtbot tutorial is great, but it's kind of obvious that all tutorials are not current.

Answer (score 0):

everything is changing too fast; the problem here resigns on loadPaths. you must check which is the right path of your files and adapt it according.

@TrueRed72 answer is clear about setting the correct load path, so he can import the file from main.scss without long paths specifications. in my case, i'm still using `<%= yeoman.app %>`, but my bower_components folder is not on project_path/app/ but on the project_path/ root. so my loadPath ended being:

```
loadPath: [
    '<%= yeoman.app %>/../bower_components/bourbon/dist/',
    '<%= yeoman.app %>/../bower_components/neat/app/assets/stylesheets/'
]
```

so... the trick is: take a look at the real files path inside bower_components folder and update your loadPath inside Gruntfile.js accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the repos have changed. This worked out for me:

in **app/styles/main.css**

```
@import "../../bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon";
@import "../../bower_components/neat/app/assets/stylesheets/neat";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's as a solution which doesn't require any re-routing of the bourbon/neat .scss paths in Gruntfile.js or main.scss, just a tinker with the *watch* task for the .scss files. This all came after getting errors similar to the other posts here.

I wanted to break the demo styling out into separate files to augment `./app/sass/main.scss` and make the whole thing more modular and user-personalised.

Firstly set up the following: `./app/sass/user/user-main.scss`.
Secondly set up the following: `./app/sass/user/02/user-secondary.scss`

Then in Gruntfile.js edit `grunt.initConfig > watch > sass > files` to read as this:

```
files: ['<%= config.app %>/sass/**/**/**/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}']
```

I edited the *files* task only, nothing else, and that is on or around line 51. Making this edit allows for grunt to auto upload when styling is edited/saved in whichever directory you work in.
You'll see that i've added wildcard selectors for 3 directories deep. I generally don't go any deeper than that if poss but that's down to the project/individual.

Then in the stylesheets i did the following:

- in main.scss left the bourbon/neat @import rules *as they are*, no changes
- in *main.scss* - *after* the bourbon/neat imports - added: `@import 'user/user-main';`
- removed *all* of the styling declarations from *main.scss* and put them inside `user/user-main.scss`
- at the bottom of `user/user-main.scss` added: `@import '02/user-secondary';`

This sass should be intuitive and the structure is just for a use-case.

With this i have cleaned up *main.scss* of all the styling declarations, and this file now serves only as the root of all styling imports. From there the project is broken out into user-specific directories/stylesheets, which is what i wanted.

Then just run `grunt build` and `grunt serve` and edits can be made to the */user/* stylesheets and the whole thing auto-loads without errors.

As a final tweak, i wanted to add some padding to the `outer-container` mixin which is applied to the `body` to stop everything going flush to the viewport edges, [as posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130887/container-padding-in-neat-bourbon). So in `user/02/user-secondary.scss` i added `@include pad(0 10px);` to *body*. It's a bit hacky as it actually reduces the width of the container, but it does apply some space at the viewport sides.

Hope this helps!